# need to create directory with database row id in linux if there is only one file inside it?

Tags: linux, django, python-2.7

I have to save Image for a Products.
There is `/var/www/product_images/` location in which I store files and add image file name in the respective Product Row into database.

e.g. suppose we upload `custom1.png` for `Product1` and `custom2.png` for `Product2`

```
/var/www/product_images/custom1.png        (product 1, row id 1)
/var/www/product_images/custom2.png        (product 2, row id 2)
```

**One Product have One Image.**

User can replace (modify) these Product image.

Issue:
  Now user use same image file name (`custom1.png`) for any other product, let say for `Product3` then these file will overwrite.

How to fix?
1. I will going to add row id to the image name during save event.
files will look like:

```
/var/www/product_images/1_custom1.png        (product 1, row id 1)
/var/www/product_images/2_custom2.png        (product 2, row id 2)   
/var/www/product_images/3_custom1.png        (product 3, row id 3)
```

2. but My senior told me to create new directory inside `/var/www/product_images` which name is according to row id and store image inside that.

files will look like:

```
/var/www/product_images/1/custom1.png        (product 1, row id 1)
/var/www/product_images/2/custom2.png        (product 2, row id 2)   
/var/www/product_images/3/custom1.png        (product 3, row id 3)
```

**Question**: Which method is better in above two?

We use CentOS Operating System, and in Linux directory also consider as file.
Coding is done in Python2.6 and Django 1.2
I think, I will go with #1

if #1 is better then what to told to senior.

Comment: Another idea would be to rename all uploaded images to unique names. So one image can be reused for different products.

Comment: yes, agree. but I have to told to senior, i.e. no need of directory, but how to told him, need some information or link to say that no need to create directory.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your filesystem, which solution is better.

If you have a lot of products, the inode count could be matter
on your file system. Then solution #1 has less overhead.
If the performance of directories with lots of files with long filenames is worse, solution #2
is better.

Comment: Agree, +1. I have structure like `/var/www/product_images/` and there are 5 lac products. so there are 5 lac directory inside `/var/www/product_images/` location and every sub-directory contains one image file.